# Error while encrypting connection string (The configuration section 'connection1' was not found.)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config, connection-string

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0>aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connection1
"C:\Website1" -prov "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider"
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'connection1' was not found.
Failed!
```

Above is screen shot of error that i getting while encrypting connection string

The web config file is as,

```
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connection1" connectionString="Data Source=inpun2-s4pvh8bs;uid=cusa;pwd=csusa;Initial Catalog=ChemTrack"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

---

Any idea about this?

I am running this from visual studio 2010 command prompt.
also a/c that i am using is member of administrator group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Website1"
```

For more : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/304638/Encrypt-or-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-web-confi

Comment: thanks. ialready tried this but it did not resolved issue. if i encrypt connection string using c# code then it will work but command prompt unable to do this task.